# Adding usercontrol to another user control

Tags: silverlight-4.0

This is my user control :-

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="NiceAnimation.ArcUserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="72" d:DesignHeight="72">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ed:Arc x:Name="arcControl" ArcThickness="20" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" Fill="#FFFF8700" Stretch="None" Stroke="Black" StartAngle="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" StrokeThickness="0"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In my MainPage.xaml.cs i am creating the user control dynamically but it's not getting created. Even no exception is fired.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random objRandom = new Random();
            for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < 30; intIndex++)
            {
                ArcUserControl objArcUserControl = new ArcUserControl();
                objArcUserControl.Opacity = 0.7;
                //objArcUserControl.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double) objRandom.Next(10, 640));
                //objArcUserControl.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)objRandom.Next(10, 480));
                objArcUserControl.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(objArcUserControl_MouseEnter);  
                //MainCanvas.Children.Add(objArcUserControl);
                canLayer1.Children.Add(objArcUserControl);

               // canLayer2.Children.Add(objArcUserControl);
               // canLayer3.Children.Add(objArcUserControl);
            }

        }

        void objArcUserControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.GetPosition(this).ToString());
        }
    }
```

What am i missing ? Further if i add `textbox` instead of usercontrol it works.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

try just adding an ArcUserControl in xaml and see if it renders.  what is canLayer1?

Comment: Thanks but only height and width was missing in usercontrol. Changed it and worked !